# A dataset using Numpy im want to remove the KM in mileage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**I have got an image attached below of a dataset in NumPy. I am trying to remove the Km in Mileage so that I can transform the object datatype to a Int or Float datatype so I can perform predictions better. How to I get rid of the characters to make this possible?**

[Image must see to understand - no code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRORf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use df['Mileage'].str[:-2] to get rid of the last two characters. Then you can convert the column to Int or Float dtypes